# How can i redirect the directory index of my old domain to a new domain page in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

My general question is how can I redirect a directory index of my old domain to a new domain directory index in the same way i would a another page on the site?

I am able on how to all individual pages on my new domain through one to a redirect. My htacess code looks like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-page.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example-page.com


DirectoryIndex front_page.php    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule   /about    /about_page.php

redirect 301 /about https://www.new_domain_example.com/about
```

Where i am having trouble is redirecting the homepage or directory index which is found at https://www.example-page.com.

I have tried

```
redirect 301 /  https://www.example-page.com
```

Also

```
Redirect 301 http://www.example-page.com   http://www.new_domain.com
```

The first doesnt work because it seems to  all pages to this domain which is undesired. All i want is to redirect the DirectoryIndex/ homepage found at the url to the new url.

The second attempt doesnt work either. At this point im quite confused as to what i could do the only thing that occurs to me is, externalising the home page. so that it looks like.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule   /front    /front_page.php

redirect 301 /front https://www.new_domain_example.com/front
```

Im sure this is not necessary and im missing something. How would you approach redirecting the front page that is as a directory index in this code without doing something that breaks the rest of my code?

Any help or insights to what i'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if you only want to redirect the home page:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/.front_page\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newdomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If  you want to redirect everything in the old domain to the new one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newdomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```